# Problems in generating example models of FeynCalc

Tags: feyncalc

I'm getting started with FeynCalc and FeynArts, so I tried to run some of the examples they give you. Everything works fine, except for the ones which require to generate a model using the scripts in FeynRules. They all give me the following error message:
SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to C:\Users\151461\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica/Applications/FeynRules.
I've tried to unistall Mathematica and FeynCalc and install them again, but nothing has changed. For clarity, I add a screenshot of the code I'm running.[image]

Comment: if you copy pasted the path then it seems a bit strange as it starts with back slashes and ends with forward slashes. Did you manually add /Applications/FeynRules ? If not it would seem that the package assumed you use Linux as /path/to/file is a Linux path. Is there an option for Windows or Linux when installing? I am not sure If I installed FeynCalc in the past and I do not know what could have caused that.

Comment: I didn't manually add it and there isn't an option for windows or linux when installing that I am aware of.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you added the path manually. The `"/Applications/FeynRules"` is how you would add a Linux path. Your Windows path uses \ so you should maybe use `<>"\Applications\FeynRules"`. If you want code that would work for any operating system you can use `FileNameJoin` so the code would be `$FeynRulesPath = SetDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "FeynRules"}]]`

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work either, the code you see in the screenshot is the one you get when you download the FeynCalc package from the official FeynCalc site, I didn't touch it.

Comment: Then they used Linux but for a tutorial that they share online they should have used `FileNameJoin`. Did you get the same error message after using `$FeynRulesPath = SetDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "FeynRules"}]]`?

Comment: Did you actually install FeynRules? It's a separate Mathematica package unrelated to FeynCalc and FeynArts that has to be downloaded from the authors' homepage: https://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't install FeynRules. Seeing the names of the directories in FeynCalc I thought it was included in the automatic installation package and I didn't know you need to install it as a separate package. Now it works, thank you all very much!